# $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not quasi isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for $m \ne n$

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Currently, I am reading geometric group theory. I came across a problem that says that  $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for $m \ne n$. We have to use Borsuk-Ulam theorem for that. But I have no idea how to do this.

Also, I know that $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{R}$ using Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Example 8.3.6 in A course in metric geometry - Burago, Burago and Ivanov. It can be proved by the fact that ${\rm vol}\ B(o,r)=C\cdot r^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3):

Say $m<n$. Borsuk-Ulam obviously implies that $\mathbf{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{R}^m$ are not homeomorphic, and even that $\mathbf{R}^n$ cannot be mapped continuously injectively into $\mathbf{R}^m$.

Assume by contradiction that there is a quasi-isometric embedding $f:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}^m$. Fix a nonprincipal ultrafilter $\omega$, and define $\tilde{f}(x)=\lim_{k\to\omega}\frac{1}{k}f(kx)$. Then $\tilde{f}$ is a bilipschitz embedding. We get a contradiction.

[If one wants to avoid ultrafilters and just use a classical countable choice, instead, use that $f_k(x)=f(kx)/k$ is bounded for all given $x$, to find a pointwise limit $g$ of the family $f_k|_{\mathbf{Q}^n}$. This pointwise limit is then a bilipschitz embedding of $\mathbf{Q}^n$ into $\mathbf{R}^m$, and hence extends to the completion as a bilipschitz embedding of $\mathbf{R}^n$ into $\mathbf{R}^m$.]

Answer (score 2):

Since $\Bbb{R}^n$ is quasi-isometric to $\Bbb{Z}^n$ it is enough to show for the question that $\Bbb{Z}^m$ is quasi-isometric to $\Bbb{Z}^n$ if and only if $m=n$. A proof of this can be easily found in  lecture notes on geometric group theory. For example, see [these notes](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Kailasa.pdf) by Kaisala, Proposition $5.7$, page $18$. For the above result see Corollary $5.8$.

Edit: Also solutions using Borsuk-Ulam can be found in such lecture notes, e.g. [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjYg-ji7OfdAhULZ1AKHbOiA0UQFjABegQICBAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.499.8956%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw3QQYDOjStLtyYpG3Iu1qg_), page $5$, or [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/axk29/pub/bmk-new.pdf), page $7$ and $8$, etc.

Comment: what you said  is absolutely right but i have not read growth rate till now . i want to prove this directly and from this we can deduce that $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ is  quasi isometric to $\mathbb{Z}^{m}$ only  when m=n.

Comment: On the other hand, it certainly could be quite useful to have a look at growth rates. The proof there seems natural to me, but I am not an expert.

Comment: The OP asked for a proof using Borsuk-Ulam. If this is no requirement, the question is a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867300/which-of-these-spaces-below-are-quasi-isometric)

Comment: @Babelfish Yes, both approaches can be found in the standard texts.

Comment: +1Thanks for adding the reference :)

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a $(\lambda,K)$-quasi-isometry and $n > m$. We will approximate it by a continuous map and then show that a precomposition with $i : S^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ gives a map violating Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

First, let's find a continuous map approximating $f$. Consider cube grid in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with vertices at $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Subdivide each $n$-cube into $n$-simplices, this gives a triangulation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with uniformly small simplices, which will become important later). Let $g :\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a map, which agrees with $f$ on points in integer coordinates, and elsewhere is given by a linear interpolation with respect to the triangulation.

If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $y \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ with $d(x,y) \leq \sqrt n/2$. Let $z \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ be a point in an $n$-simplex containing $x$ furthest from $y$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d(f(x),g(x)) \leq d(f(x),f(y)) + d(f(y),g(y)) + d(g(y),g(x)) \\
\leq (\lambda \sqrt n/2 + K) + 0 + (\lambda d(y,z) +K) \\
\leq \frac{3}{2}\lambda \sqrt n + 2K
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Let $i:S^m \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be an inclusion, which embeds $S^m$ as a sphere of radius $R$. Then $g \circ i$ is continuous map.

If $x$ and $-x$ is a pair of antipodal points on $i(S^m) \subset R^n$, then

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d(g(x), g(-x)) \geq d(f(x), f(-x)) -3 \lambda \sqrt n - 4K \\
\geq \frac{2R}{\lambda} -3 \lambda \sqrt n - 5K
\end{split}
\end{equation}

If we take $R > \frac{\lambda}{2}(3 \lambda \sqrt n + 5K)$, the right-hand side is positive and $g(x) \ne g(-x)$. This contradicts Borsak-Ulam theorem.

Comment: can you please elaborate more about the subdivision into n - simplices and about the map gand its continuity?