# Example of groups that are not quasi-isometric but have the same growth rate?

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

I have started working on group growth earlier this year, mainly using Drutu and Kapovich's notes. This morning I found myself wondering if I could find an example of groups that are not quasi-isometric but have the same growth rate. Spontaneously, I thought about finite groups, groups of linear growth and free groups. All those cannot provide such an example.

I firmly believe this to be possible but I have been unable to find one. Google searches have not helped me either so maybe some of you can.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Different growth rates imply non-quasi-isometry, but I'm not sure the converse is obvious. I feel like I once saw a counter example, but I can't remember where or what it was unfortunately

Comment: You could try asking this on mathoverflow.

Comment: My answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444518/are-there-any-usages-for-growth-rate-that-are-relatively-easy-to-show/4445292#4445292) gives the simplest example in the realm of groups of polynomial growth: both $\mathbb Z^4$ and the integer Heisenberg group have polynomial growth of degree 4.

Comment: Thank you @LeeMosher, it looks exactly like what I need

Comment: The class of groups with exponential growth is quite huge and contains plenty of non-quasi-isometric groups. For instance, $F_2$ and $F_2\times F_2$ are not quasi-isometric. There are many subclasses that are known to be QI-closed, e.g., (non-elementary hyperbolic) $\subsetneq$ (finitely presented of exponential growth) $\subsetneq$ (exponential growth). Polynomial growth examples are more restricted but anyway do exist, as indicated by Lee Mosher, although the full classification of QI among polynomial growth groups is still conjectural.

Answer (score 8):

To augment the answer of @QiaochuYuan, I'll turn my comment into an answer: In the realm of groups of polynomial growth, the simplest example is that both $\mathbb Z^4$ and the integer Heisenberg group have polynomial growth of degree $4$.

One still has to prove that those groups are not quasi-isometric to each other. The simplest proof that I know is that $\mathbb Z^4$ acts freely, properly and cocompactly on the topological space $\mathbb R^4$ hence its cohomological dimension is $4$; whereas the integer Heisenberg group acts freely, properly and cocompactly on $\mathbb R^3$ hence its cohomological dimension is $3$. And in the realm of groups that act freely, properly and cocompactly on Euclidean spaces (or even on contractible CW complexes), the cohomological dimension is a quasi-isometry invariant.

Answer (score 5):

This is not at all an area I know about, but some quick googling gives the following:

- The fundamental group of any closed hyperbolic $n$-manifold is quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{H}^n$, and any two such fundamental groups (for $n \ge 2$) have exponential growth rate.
- $\mathbb{H}^n$ and $\mathbb{H}^m$ are [not quasi-isometric if $n \neq m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228697/how-to-see-the-various-hyperbolic-n-spaces-mathbbhn-arent-quasi-isometr); they can be distinguished by their [Gromov boundaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov_boundary), which are $S^{n-1}$ and $S^{m-1}$ respectively.

So we can take the fundamental groups of a closed hyperbolic $n$-manifold and $m$-manifold for $n \neq m \ge 2$.

Comment: Looks promissing but I am not able to understand this yet